# Which sport has the most players?

Tags: trivia, international-sports

Which *widely-played* sport has the most active *players* globally?

By *widely-played*, I mean played in at least ten countries.

By *players*, I mean both professional and amateur players who play in an organised competition.

Comment: How do you define "play it". Recreationally; apart of a team in a league; once a year?

Comment: Right comment up for you. Both: pro and amateur

Comment: I've had a go at narrowing it and making it more concise. Let me know if I've changed the question too much.

Comment: Are you asking for team sports or team and individual players/sports?

Comment: @Don_Biglia Right comment up also for you. Both: team and individual sports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This list](http://sporteology.com/top-10-popular-sports-world/) appears to be quite a definitive list and is more or less where I'd expect it to be in terms of the top 10.

Stating Soccer as the most played and (mainly because of the massive player numbers on the sub-continent) Cricket at number 2.

Comment: That's a good find, but it looks like the list is ranking number of fans (determined by which sports are the most watched), not number of players.  Although, the two stats are probably correlated somewhat.

Comment: This image https://twitter.com/Amazing_Maps/status/630470784205619200/photo/1 confirm that football is the sport with the most spectator with the large majority so it is also the sport with more players

Answer (score -10):

Baseball. What else could it be?

Comment: Could you provide some references for this answer? It seems unlikely to me to be true given the limited geographic distribution of baseball - how many Chinese and Indians play baseball?