# Which is the most popular game in Australia?

Tags: football, rugby-union, rugby, australian-rules-football, rugby-league

Which is the most popular football code in Australia both in terms of number of active players, and spectator attendance?

Comment: What do you mean with "most popular"? Most players? Most attendance? Most viewership? My question (http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/10291/which-sport-has-the-most-players) on this topic has no find interest from users

Comment: I have edited the question to attempt to narrow the scope of the question and make it answerable. If this does not reflect your original intent, please feel free to revert my changes.

Answer (score 6):

As written in the comment is not clear what do you mean with "most popular".

I can try to reply to the question whinking about popularity like attendance.

So according to those sources ([guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/interactive/2014/apr/15/australia-football-interactive-statistics) and [Australian Bureau of Statistics](http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/Latestproducts/4174.0Main%20Features52009-10?opendocument&tabname=Summary&prodno=4174.0&issue=2009-10&num=&view=)) **Australian (rules) Football** seems the "most popular" sport in that country.

The sources not agreed on all data, but it seems that this sport is the top on both the rankings.

On other hand the sport with most players seems **football**.

On the picture belows some images from guardian source: from the last one is possible to notice that only football has an official women League

[image: Average weekly attendance]
[image: Average viewer and number of players]
[image: Other info]

Comment: A quote from the relevant sources (perhaps with some figures) would make this a better answer. Links can disappear. This answer also does not correctly quote the data. Association football (soccer) has the most number of active players by a factor of 2, according to the Guardian source.

Comment: @studro up for your comment, but the question ask for the most popular AND has the most players. So the question is not clear and I reply to the most popular meaning with the most attendance. I have edited the reply to be more clear

Comment: That's a lot better. Figures from the source would still make this much a better answer.

Comment: This is now a very strong answer. Thank you.